# Is there any alternative of converting the JSON response into a custom Dart object?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and dart and making an application with nodejs backend with MongoDB as my database. When requesting data from flutter using HTTP package I noticed I have to convert the JSON to a custom Dart object.

I referred to the official [document](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#:%7E:text=3.-,Convert%20the%20response%20into%20a%20custom%20Dart%20object,-While%20it%E2%80%99s%20easy)

Everything is working fine, but I find this conversion of data a very long process and unnecessary line of code if I have many different pages with a different types of data coming from the backend.

Is there any quick or better way to accomplish this?
Thank you

Comment: Is not necessary not convert the json to a dart object you can just access each property with json['key'], but having a dart object will help you to have a more organize code and structure.

Comment: Well, the conversion to custom objects is really just a convenience. You don't have to do it if you don't want. You could just work with the response data directly. But I advice you to create the objects. I would advise using tools for that. https://app.quicktype.io/ is a nice one. You just paste your response and it generates the necessary object class. It has some flaws but it does the most work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart is an Object Oriented Programming language.

That's why the official documentation is talking about converting your Json into a Dart Object :)
You could achieve the same things by having your Jsons as `Maps<String, dynamic>` instead of converting it to Dart Objects, but at the cost of an unnecessary complex code.

If you have a lot of models to use, you can use a library generating the parsing methods for you like [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) thank to some annotation processing, or even [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) which is generating even more useful methods.

Basic example of json_serializable :

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user_agenda.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class UserAgenda {
  String? uid;
  String? name;
  String? imgUrl;
  int? nextDate;

  UserAgenda() {}

  factory UserAgenda.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserAgendaFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserAgendaToJson(this);

}
```

*Personal opinion : in your case, go for json_serializable. Freezed may be overkill, and playing with the Maps will shortly become a real pain to maintain.*

Answer (score 0):

For Converting JSON Response to Dart object you should use [https://app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/)

Select Language as Dart.
Please note that generated code will not a null safe code. so you have to take care of it.

Comment: Please stop recommending that site. The Dart part has not been updated for ages and does not support null-safety which means it generate a lot of questionable or broken code.

Comment: @julemand101 yah that`s what I`m saying do you know alternative one?? please??

Comment: @nounlace I, personally, prefer to do stuff manually. Maybe with some amount of generated code. I recommend reading: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the response to the Dart objects you made before. Just use

```
  Map<String, dynamic> answer = jsonDecode(response.body);
```

Then you can access any value by it's key like this:

```
 var x = answer['key1'][0]['key2'];
```

But You need to know each time the structure of JSON.

Comment: That's not really a quicker nor better way to handle a data-model. It'd work indeed, but it'd be much more complex to implement, use and maintain

Comment: Yes, it is can only be used in simple responses with light structure, there you don't need to handle all fields. The better way is to use data-models.